# Dojo AMD 1.7 proper inheritance syntax using declare

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dojo, js-amd

I am struggling with this one:

I have this simple module in a file Module1.js:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'esri/map'], function (declare, map) {
    return declare(null,
        {
            name: "Module 1 name",

            constructor: function() {
                this.name = "module 1";
                //this.age = age;
                //this.currentResidence = currentResidence;
            },


            doSomething: function() {
                alert("calling from Module1");
            }
        });
});
```

I am trying to define a Module2 that inherits from Module1 but cannot seem to find the correct syntax:  This is what I currently have:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "esri/map",
        "tut/Module1"],
    function (declare, map, Module1) {
        return declare(null, [Module1],     // or tut/Module1
        {
            name: "Module 2 name",

            constructor: function () {
                this.name = "module 2";
                //this.age = age;                 
            },


            doSomething: function () {
                this.inherited(arguments); // Call superclass method...
                alert("calling from Module 2");
            },

            doSomething1: function () {
                alert("calling do soething 1 from module 2");
            }
        });
});
```

Somewhere else in my code, I am doing this:

```
  require(["tut/Module1", "tut/Module2"], function (Module1, Module2) {        
        var m = new Module1();
        m.doSomething();

        var m2 = new Module2();
        m2.doSomething();    

    });
```

I have the following dojoConfig defined just before I load the ESRI script that loads dojo as follows:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
   var dojoConfig = {
                async : true,                               
                packages: [{ name: "tut", location: liveString + '/scripts/xxxx/utilities'}]            
            };
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.0compact"></script>
```

The call to Module1 works indicating to me that my packages definition is correct.  However, the call to Module2 throws an exception that says Object [object object] has no method 'doSomething'.  I have tried some many different permutations, going back and forth with the [manual](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/declare.html)  but cannot find the right syntax.  Now I am just guessing so will need some help.

How do I inherit from Module1 using Dojo 1.7 syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `this.inherited(arguments)` will work (if declare doesnt throw 'not a valid mixin', and neither constructor method throws errors).

Try

#### module 1

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "esri/map"],
    function (declare, map) {
        return declare("tut.Module1", [], {     // or tut>>.<<Module1
          constructor: function() { this.name='a'; console.log('a ctor'); }
          log: function() { console.log(this.name); }
        });
    }
});
```

#### module 2 derived from module 1

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
        "esri/map",
        "tut/Module1"],
    function (declare, map, Module1) {
        return declare("tut.Module2", [Module1],
          constructor: function() { this.name='B'; console.log('B ctor'); }
          log: function() { this.inherited(arguments); console.log(this.name); }
        });
    }
});
```

Try iterating over the constructor._meta 'bases' in a module instance ('new Module().constructor._meta') and that should give an idea of how this.inherited works

Calling

```
require(["tut/Module2"], function (M2) {
   var m = new M2();
   console.log('created');
   m.log()
});
```

would output

"B ctor"
"A ctor"
"created"
"A"
"B"

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Comparing your Module definitions and the ones I posted, the main difference is that you are explicitly setting the Module names to "tut.Module1" and "tut.Module2".  This is where either the documentation is unclear or I got confused.  In this link  "http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/declare/"  is a statement that says "Named classes should only be created if they will be used with the Dojo parser. All other classes should omit the className paramete". But in the docs for "declare" all you samples use a Module name.  I think this area needs clarification.

Comment: agreed.. have had a few struggles in the area myself - i believe that the 'inherited' function uses the said constructor._meta data and these is not initialized in correct manner if the declaredName is missing.